# Define function to return sample covariance

Tags: python

I have two vectors, I am trying to use them in a function to return just the sample covariance.
Can anyone help me fix my program? I am new to python and programming in general.

```
xv= array([8., 9.5, 7.8, 4.2, -7.7, -5.4, 3.2])
yv= array([8.9, 2.0, 4.8, -4.2, 2.7, -3.4, -5.9])

def cov(x,y):
    if (len(x) != len(y)
        [Stop] 
        x.bar = mean(x) 
        y.bar = mean(y) 
        N = len(x)      
    Cov = (sum((x-x.bar)*(y-y.bar))) / (N-1.0) 
    return(Cov)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the current code?

Comment: starting at x.bar = mean(y)...I am getting invalid syntax message.  Not sure why?

Comment: x.bar is not a proper variable name; don't use '.' in variable names; x_bar or xbar is what you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version without using external libraries. The equation for covariance is from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance

```
x = [8., 9.5, 7.8, 4.2, -7.7, -5.4, 3.2]
y = [8.9, 2.0, 4.8, -4.2, 2.7, -3.4, -5.9]

def mean(x):
    return sum(x) / len(x)

def cov(x, y):
    x_mean = mean(x)
    y_mean = mean(y)
    data = [(x[i] - x_mean) * (y[i] - y_mean)
            for i in range(len(x))]
    return sum(data) / (len(data) - 1)

print cov(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this ran correctly. But I am just looking for the sample covariance. I believe its 12.495 out of the matrix that was returned. Is it because our formulas are different?

Comment: Do expect a matrix to be returned? Since there are just two variables, the value returned is the covariance between the two.

Comment: I was expecting just one number returned. Just the sample covariance.

Comment: The current function does return one number. So what is the problem?

Comment: Nevermind I was confused for a second but am not anymore. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try taking a look at the widely used `numpy` package for operations like covariance:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your function this way that works:

```
def cov(x,y):
    if (len(x) != len(y)):
        sys.exit()
    x_bar = float(sum(x)/len(x))
    y_bar = float(sum(y)/len(y))
    N = len(x)
    sum_xy = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sum_xy += (x[i]-x_bar)*(y[i]-y_bar)
    return(sum_xy/(N-1.0))
```